# Class instances working together directly

Tags: java, design-patterns, instance

I have been puzzled about this for quite a while. (Forgive me, I'm a beginner) Is there a good design pattern where class instances interact together without the interference of the superclass, or at least at a minimum level? I would like to create instances that are fully independent. But in order to interact with others, they need to have a notion of the world around it. I have the feeling there must be an elegant way to directly access other instances' methods.. or? Simply put: I want a situation where my Environment class creates my instances and then calls interact().

Comment: You really need to ask a more specific question.  Interact how?  Have you looked at the Spring Framework?  It has a lot of mechanisms that combine independent classes using annotation and reflection.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly check that out. 'interacting' could be anything, think: monsters in a game, every one equipped with unique behaviors. When put together and let alone this gives rise to a chain reaction, resulting in a bloody mess..

Comment: Just came across the mediator design pattern which seems to be the preferred way to set things up. I guess that by definition in OOP there is no way to have 'colleagues' exchanging information in a direct manner. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composition is what you are after, like you suggested. Try to achieve loose coupling as much as possible to maintain a strictly object oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. But take a look at these lines of code:

```
Environment env = new Environment();
env.interact();
```

Or:

```
EnvironmentInteracter envInt = new EnvironmentInteracter(env);
envInt.makeInteractionHappen();
```

Where,

```
public class EnvironmentInteracter
{

     private Environment env;
     public EnvironmentInteracter(Environment env) { this.env = env; }

     public void makeInteractionHappen()
     {
          env.interact();
     }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me more like shifting the problem.. In this case we still need the 'agent' class (EnvironmentInteracter) to lead the process of interacting, don't you agree?

Comment: Yeah, my example is weak, indeed. But that gives you an idea on how to work with multiple classes together.